# Javascript Regular Expression for whole word match which may contains special characters also

Tags: javascript, regex

I have to find matches of search terms in a document of text. I am coding in Javascript.
I used \b for whole word match. But I facing one problem. The search Term will contain some special characters also.

**example one:**

Text: `This article contains information on the Installment Loan-IL Profile which allows the teammate to view the details of a client’s Installment Loan IL.`

SearchTerm: "`IL`"

and Regex Exp I used is `"\b(IL)\b"`. It is working fine

---

**example two:**

Text:

```
The online New Account Center (NAC) is an automated way for prospects and clients to open consumer checking, savings, and money market accounts online through..
```

SearchTerm: "`New Account Center(NAC)`"

and Regex Exp I used is `"\b(New Account Center\\(NAC\\))\b"`.
It is not working because of the `)` in the end.

Please help me with a Regular expression which can accommodate both scenarios.

Comment: In your input text there is a space before `(NAC)`

Comment: It is not working because there are a space before `(NAC)`

Comment: You need to account for whitespace. i.e `(\bIL\b|\bNew Account Center\s*\(NAC\))`

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
/\b(IL\b|New\s*Account\s*Center\s*\(NAC\))/g
```

If it's a single word without any whitespaces/delimeter , you can go ahead to include `\b` both at the front and at the back , else you use the above format.

You need to escape the white spaces as above.